# Visual Basic 2008 - Me.Controls - Textboxes - NULL -

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox

Self taught(in progress) Visual Basic guy here.

I've searched for a clear answer on this, but so far have come up empty handed.

The problem...

1. I have two comboboxes. The first combobox has 10 options, second combobox has 2 options
2. I have 10 textboxes, with a name that includes one of the 10 options.

   ex 1st textbox name - "txb_Option1Type"

   2nd textbox name - "txb_Option2Type" and so on.
3. I have 2 tabs, with the first 5 text boxes on the 1st tab and last 5 on the 2nd tab.
4. I thought the following bit of code, upon a button click, would transfer the text of the chosen option in the 2nd combobox to the corresponding textbox...

` 
Public Sub TransferTruckToDoorText()

```
    Dim str_ErrorButton As String = cbx_DoorNumber.Text

    Dim str_ReplaceSpacesButton As String = str_ErrorButton.Replace(" ", "")

    Dim str_Button As String = str_ReplaceSpacesButton
```

' Null reference error on below line of code

```
    Me.Controls("txb_" & str_Button & "Type").Text = cbx_TruckType.Text


End Sub
```

`

As noted in the above code, I'm getting a null reference and for the life of me cannot figure out why. I've stepped through the code, and I'm not able to find a NULL or Nothing value that could be making this catch.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

edited for clarity

Comment: Use the debugger to see what the value of str_Button is.  Make sure these controls are not in a panel, etc.

Comment: The value of the str_Button is the selected option from the first combobox, minus the spaces.
Not sure what you mean by "not in a panel".

Comment: Don't keep str_Button a secret.  What did the debugger tell you the value was?  You are only looking for these controls in "Me".  If these controls are in a Panel or a GroupBox, etc, they won't be there.  They would be in the Panel's Controls collection, etc.

Comment: Apologies. Didn't mean to be cryptic. When option 1 is chosen, the value is "Option1".  I have the text boxes separated between two tabs(should of mentioned that in retrospect). Does that affect it?

Comment: Yep.  TabControls have TabPages.  Try using `Me.Controls.Find(controlname, True)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Me.Controls collection does not automatically search the child panels.

Try using the Controls.Find method for that, which includes a parameter to search the child control's control collection, too.  It returns an array:

```
Dim c As Control() = Me.Controls.Find("txb_" & str_Button & "Type", True)
If c.Length = 1 Then
  c(0).Text = cbx_TruckType.Text
End If
```

Comment: This works, thank you!
A couple of questions on this...
1. How does .Length work in this? What if .Length was "2"?
2. If I wanted to expand this and want to have 2 values to be passed based on the option chosen. Let's add "txb_Option1Customer" for example. How would I include this?
Or would that be an entirely different question that I should post?

Comment: @user3485244 Length is the number of elements in the array.  If you get zero, then it didn't find your control by the name.  If it finds more than one, then you have duplicate controls on your form that have the same name, which shouldn't really happen, especially if you used the designer to create the controls.

Comment: @user3485244 Not sure what you mean.  You could make your own method `Private Sub SetControlText(controlName As String, textValue As String)` then include the code in the post above, making the obvious modifications.

Comment: If I had a third combobox to choose an option from. cbx_CustomerName, and I wanted to transfer that choice to a corresponding textbox based on the value of str_button. 
So now instead of passing only 1 value (cbx_TruckType.Text) I would be also sending cbx_CustomerName.Text.

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.Controls.Item("txb_" & str_Button & "Type")
```